# 'history of' vs 'history about'

Tags: grammar, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

Lovely community, when checking my review with the Grammarly Premium, in the sentence

> 'A Beautiful Mind' is a history about an extraordinary mathematician, John Nash.

it underlined **about** and instead suggested **of**.

Is *history about* also possible? Or *history of* is the only grammatically correct way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The phrase "a history **of**... somebody" is more natural, but you might say "a **story** about...something". I would add another suggestion and write "a history of **the** extraordinary mathematician, John Nash."

Comment: Thanks for your comment! In a nutshell, you mean 'history about' is grammatically correct, but a bit unnatural?

Comment: I like their suggestion, but as mentioned, prefer '**of the**' because Nash is well known since the Russell Crowe movie.

Comment: Very obliged! :)

Comment: We cannot say for sure that it is grammatically incorrect to write 'history about', but sounds somewhat unnatural

Comment: Some languages use the same word for _history_ and _story_, but in English _history_ has the distinct meaning of 'writing about the past'. There is, however, a tradition of using it in the _title_ of a story about a person (now rather old-fashioned) - but it's always "The history _of_ …"